# Why is Spark application's final status FAILED while it finishes successfully?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My application Spark 2.0.0 runs on yarn 2.7.2. It finishes successfully but Yarn marks it as failed with error:

```
Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 16, (reason: Shutdown hook called     before final status was reported.)
```

I see no errors on executors nor driver and application writes the data it is supposed to.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be caused by calling System.exit( 0 ) specifically in my code. After removing it the problem is gone

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45524760/215945 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872955/215945