# Spark jobs running on EMR cluster. system.exit(0) used to gracefully completion of job but still Step on EMR fails

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

In spark job. I am using if file not found the system.exit(0). It should gracefully complete the job. Locally It is successfully completed. But when I am running on EMR. Step is failing.

Comment: What is the error reported in the log files on EMR?

Answer (score 8):

EMR uses [YARN](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) for cluster management and launching Spark applications. So when you're running a Spark app with `--deploy-mode: cluster` in EMR, the Spark application code is not running in a JVM on its own, but is rather executed by the [`ApplicationMaster`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6567fc43aca75b41900cde976594e21c8b0ca98a/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala) class.

Browsing through the `ApplicationMaster` code can explain what happens when you try to execute `System.exit()`. The user application is launched in [`startUserApplication`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6567fc43aca75b41900cde976594e21c8b0ca98a/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala#L648), and then the `finish` method is called after the user application returns. However, when you call `System.exit(0)`, what is executed instead is [a shutdown hook](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6567fc43aca75b41900cde976594e21c8b0ca98a/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala#L276) which sees that your code hasn't finished successfully, and marks it as an `EXIT_EARLY` failure. It also has this useful comment:

```
  // The default state of ApplicationMaster is failed if it is invoked by shut down hook.
  // This behavior is different compared to 1.x version.
  // If user application is exited ahead of time by calling System.exit(N), here mark
  // this application as failed with EXIT_EARLY. For a good shutdown, user shouldn't call
  // System.exit(0) to terminate the application.
```

Comment: is their a proper way to trigger a job complete ? other than just waiting for the `main` to return nothing ?

Comment: You'd probably need to find a way to return from the main method when you want to complete the job. For example, a somewhat hacky way could be to throw an exception from the completion point you want, catch that exception in `main`, and then exit gracefully there. There might be better ways depending on how your code is structured.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Is there a way to "catch" a system.exit ? If a library is calling it and I need to bypass it.

Comment: Not that I know of. The only approach I’m aware of is by using a SecurityManager - however, this is what YARN already does, and it seems like it’s not possible to have multiple security managers registered in the same Java application. There’s a general discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401281/preventing-system-exit-from-api , but that seems to be the only approach mentioned there too.